# Typhoeus gem is not fetching the primary IP

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, typhoeus

I am using Typhoeus gem to run HTTP request. But when I am running in another system its running fine and returning the correct primary IP. But in my system it's not giving the primary IP -- instead of that it returns nil.

My code is like

```
request = Typhoeus.post("www.google.com")
```

response in another system:

Typhoeus::Response:0xb45c1f70 @options={:httpauth_avail=>0, :total_time=>0.101638, :starttransfer_time=>0.10146, :appconnect_time=>0.0, :pretransfer_time=>0.035663, :connect_time=>0.035659, :namelookup_time=>0.00018, :effective_url=>"http://www.google.com", :primary_ip=>"74.125.236.48", :response_code=>405, :redirect_count=>0, :return_code=>:ok,

response in my system:

Typhoeus::Response:0xbc9704c @options={:httpauth_avail=>0, :total_time=>0.589821, :starttransfer_time=>0.419524, :appconnect_time=>nil, :pretransfer_time=>0.194883, :connect_time=>0.194829, :namelookup_time=>0.02522, :effective_url=>"http://www.google.com", :primary_ip=>nil, :response_code=>200, :redirect_count=>0, :return_code=>:ok,

I want to know why its happening like this. I am waiting for good answer.

**UPDATED**

FULL RESPONSE from another system:

Typhoeus::Response:0xb4cebdb4 @options={:httpauth_avail=>0, :total_time=>0.077503, :starttransfer_time=>0.077249, :appconnect_time=>0.0, :pretransfer_time=>0.013626, :connect_time=>0.01362, :namelookup_time=>0.000143, :effective_url=>"http://www.google.com", :primary_ip=>"74.125.236.50", :response_code=>405, :redirect_count=>0, :return_code=>:ok, :response_headers=>"HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed\r\nAllow: GET, HEAD\r\nDate: Thu, 10 Apr 2014 12:42:44 GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nServer: gws\r\nContent-Length: 1453\r\nX-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\nX-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\nAlternate-Protocol: 80:quic\r\n\r\n", :response_body=>"\n\n  \n  \n  Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)!!1\n  \n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2.png) no-repeat}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:55px;width:150px}\n  \n  \n

**405.** That\xE2\x80\x99s an error.\n

The request method `POST` is inappropriate for the URL `/`.  That\xE2\x80\x99s all we know.\n", :debug_info=>#}, @request=#:post}, @options={:method=>:post, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"Typhoeus - https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus"}, :maxredirs=>50}, @on_headers=[], @response=#, @on_complete=[], @on_failure=[]>

FULL RESPONSE from MY system:

Typhoeus::Response:0xbf277e4 @options={:httpauth_avail=>0, :total_time=>0.542332, :starttransfer_time=>0.374829, :appconnect_time=>nil, :pretransfer_time=>0.192083, :connect_time=>0.192035, :namelookup_time=>0.025185, :effective_url=>"http://www.google.com", :primary_ip=>nil, :response_code=>200, :redirect_count=>0, :return_code=>:ok, :response_headers=>"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Thu, 10 Apr 2014 12:44:38 GMT\r\nExpires: -1\r\nCache-Control: private, max-age=0\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\nSet-Cookie: PREF=ID=075796115d23a806:FF=0:TM=1397133878:LM=1397133878:S=9K9PiB355V_pLs56; expires=Sat, 09-Apr-2016 12:44:38 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com\r\nSet-Cookie: NID=67=lbUdPyBSFruSAjPvOJZJhr25WNN43JzP--0oYtYxHvMxYYJqeWZBj8wRZi6qMPxw7XPHHylholrcflVZ-SpIdci8GL_guJcfAnh1O8XJHKQb3Qu67MA62L-bhlCbvgST; expires=Fri, 10-Oct-2014 12:44:38 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly\r\nP3P: CP=\"This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info.\"\r\nServer: gws\r\nX-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\nX-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\nAlternate-Protocol: 80:quic\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n\r\n", :response_body=>"http://schema.org/WebPage\" lang=\"en\">Google(function(){\nwindow.google={kEI:\"NpJGU4rKMeWCiQe46IGABA\",getEI:function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute(\"eid\")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI},https:function(){return\"https:\"==window.location.protocol},kEXPI:\"17259,4000116,4007661,4007830,4008067,4008133,4008142,4009033,4009565,4009641,4010806,4010858,4010899,4011228,4011258,4011679,4012373,4012504,4012508,4013374,4013414,4013591,4013723,4013747,4013757,4013787,4013823,4013967,4013979,4014016,4014431,4014515,4014636,4014671,4014810,4014813,4014909,4014991,4015119,4015155,4015234,4015260,4015444,4015497,4015519,4015550,4015589,4015638,4015639,4015642,4015644,4015646,4015685,4015772,4015812,4015853,4015900,4016007,4016031,4016127,4016309,4016323,4016326,4016331,4016367,4016373,4016452,4016456,4016466,4016479,4016487,4016623,4016643,4016703,4016730,4016851,4016902,4016969,8300015,8300017,8500165,8500223,8500239,8500252,8500256,8500283,8500306,10200002,10200012,10200013,10200029,10200038,10200040,10200045,10200048,10200053,10200055,10200066,10200083,10200103,10200120,10200134,10200136,10200155,10200157,10200159,10200178\",kCSI:{e:\"17259,4000116,4007661,4007830,4008067,4008133,4008142,4009033,4009565,4009641,4010806,4010858,4010899,4011228,4011258,4011679,4012373,4012504,4012508,4013374,4013414,4013591,4013723,4013747,4013757,4013787,4013823,4013967,4013979,4014016,4014431,4014515,4014636,4014671,4014810,4014813,4014909,4014991,4015119,4015155,4015234,4015260,4015444,4015497,4015519,4015550,4015589,4015638,4015639,4015642,4015644,4015646,4015685,4015772,4015812,4015853,4015900,4016007,4016031,4016127,4016309,4016323,4016326,4016331,4016367,4016373,4016452,4016456,4016466,4016479,4016487,4016623,4016643,4016703,4016730,4016851,4016902,4016969,8300015,8300017,8500165,8500223,8500239,8500252,8500256,8500283,8500306,10200002,10200012,10200013,10200029,10200038,10200040,10200045,10200048,10200053,10200055,10200066,10200083,10200103,10200120,10200134,10200136,10200155,10200157,10200159,10200178\",ei:\"NpJGU4rKMeWCiQe46IGABA\"},authuser:0,ml:function(){},kHL:\"en\",time:function(){return(new Date).getTime()},log:function(a,b,c,h,k){var d=\nnew Image,f=google.lc,e=google.li,g=\"\";d.onerror=d.onload=d.onabort=function(){delete f[e]};f[e]=d;c||-1!=b.search(\"&ei=\")||(g=\"&ei=\"+google.getEI(h));c=c||\"/\"+(k||\"gen_204\")+\"?atyp=i&ct=\"+a+\"&cad=\"+b+g+\"&zx=\"+google.time();a=/^http:/i;a.test(c)&&google.https()?(google.ml(Error(\"GLMM\"),!1,{src:c}),delete f[e]):(d.src=c,google.li=e+1)},lc:[],li:0,y:{},x:function(a,b){google.y[a.id]=[a,b];return!1},load:function(a,b,c){google.x({id:a+l++},function(){google.load(a,b,c)})}};var l=0;})();\n(function(){google.sn=\"webhp\";google.timers={};google.startTick=function(a,b){google.timers[a]={t:{start:google.time()},bfr:!!b}};google.tick=function(a,b,g){google.timers[a]||google.startTick(a);google.timers[a].t[b]=g||google.time()};google.startTick(\"load\",!0);\ntry{}catch(d){}})();\nvar _gjwl=location;function _gjuc(){var a=_gjwl.href.indexOf(\"#\");if(0<=a&&(a=_gjwl.href.substring(a),0#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important;}#gbar{height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-right:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}.gbi .gb4{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gb4{color:#900 !important}body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}body{margin:0;overflow-y:scroll}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}.h{color:#36c}.q{color:#00c}.ts td{padding:0}.ts{border-collapse:collapse}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{height:25px;width:496px}.gsfi,.lst{font:18px arial,sans-serif}.gsfs{font:17px arial,sans-serif}.ds{display:inline-box;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-left:4px}input{font-family:inherit}a.gb1,a.gb2,a.gb3,a.gb4{color:#11c !important}body{background:#fff;color:black}a{color:#11c;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:underline}.fl a{color:#36c}a:visited{color:#551a8b}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline}a.gb3:hover{text-decoration:none}#ghead a.gb2:hover{color:#fff !important}.sblc{padding-top:5px}.sblc a{display:block;margin:2px 0;margin-left:13px;font-size:11px}.lsbb{background:#eee;border:solid 1px;border-color:#ccc #999 #999 #ccc;height:30px}.lsbb{display:block}.ftl,#fll a{display:inline-block;margin:0 12px}.lsb{background:url(/images/srpr/nav_logo80.png) 0 -258px repeat-x;border:none;color:#000;cursor:pointer;height:30px;margin:0;outline:0;font:15px arial,sans-serif;vertical-align:top}.lsb:active{background:#ccc}.lst:focus{outline:none}#addlang a{padding:0 3px}(function(){var src='/images/nav_logo176.png';var iesg=false;document.body.onload = function(){window.n && window.n();if (document.images){new Image().src=src;}\nif (!iesg){document.f&&document.f.q.focus();document.gbqf&&document.gbqf.q.focus();}\n}\n})(); Search http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi\">Images http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl\">Maps https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8\">Play http://www.youtube.com/?tab=w1\">YouTube http://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn\">News https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm\">Gmail https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo\">Drive http://www.google.com/intl/en/options/\">More »http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en\" class=gb4>Web History | Settings | https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=http://www.google.com/\" class=gb4>Sign in  
 Advanced searchLanguage tools
Advertising ProgramsBusiness Solutionshttps://plus.google.com/116899029375914044550\" rel=\"publisher\">+GoogleAbout Google© 2013 - Privacy & Terms

if(google.y)google.y.first=[];(function(){function b(a){window.setTimeout(function(){var c=document.createElement(\"script\");c.src=a;document.getElementById(\"xjsd\").appendChild(c)},0)}google.dljp=function(a){google.xjsu=a;b(a)};google.dlj=b;})();\nif(!google.xjs){window._=window._||{};window._._DumpException=function(e){throw e};if(google.timers&&google.timers.load.t){google.timers.load.t.xjsls=new Date().getTime();}google.dljp('/xjs/_/js/k\\x3dxjs.hp.en_US.75bv2nh_qxI.O/m\\x3dsb_he,pcc/rt\\x3dj/d\\x3d1/sv\\x3d1/rs\\x3dAItRSTOX5WMsAVpkgEafYeVKZ7ZCJdNXcg');google.xjs=1;}google.pmc={\"sb_he\":{\"agen\":true,\"cgen\":true,\"client\":\"heirloom-hp\",\"dh\":true,\"ds\":\"\",\"eqch\":true,\"fl\":true,\"host\":\"google.com\",\"jam\":0,\"jsonp\":true,\"msgs\":{\"dym\":\"Did you mean:\",\"lcky\":\"I\\u0026#39;m Feeling Lucky\",\"lml\":\"Learn more\",\"oskt\":\"Input tools\",\"psrc\":\"This search was removed from your \\u003Ca href=\\\"/history\\\"\\u003EWeb History\\u003C/a\\u003E\",\"psrl\":\"Remove\",\"sbit\":\"Search by image\",\"srch\":\"Google Search\"},\"ovr\":{},\"pq\":\"\",\"qcpw\":false,\"scd\":10,\"sce\":5,\"stok\":\"nXO_Z2rNte7VdOqPtwZ_V-hNE4c\"},\"pcc\":{}};google.y.first.push(function(){if(google.med){google.med('init');google.initHistory();google.med('history');}});if(google.j&&google.j.en&&google.j.xi){window.setTimeout(google.j.xi,0);}(function(){if(google.timers&&google.timers.load.t){var b,c,d,e,g=function(a,f){a.removeEventListener?(a.removeEventListener(\"load\",f,!1),a.removeEventListener(\"error\",f,!1)):(a.detachEvent(\"onload\",f),a.detachEvent(\"onerror\",f))},h=function(a){e=(new Date).getTime();++c;a=a||window.event;a=a.target||a.srcElement;g(a,h)},k=document.getElementsByTagName(\"img\");b=k.length;for(var l=c=0,m;l", :debug_info=>#}, @request=#:post}, @options={:method=>:post, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"Typhoeus - https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus"}, :maxredirs=>50}, @on_headers=[], @response=#, @on_complete=[], @on_success=[]>

Comment: btw the response from the other system has a 405 and yours a 200.. very weird..

Comment: are you sure the method is `post` for both requests? I only get a `405` code when I use `post`

Comment: i am using post for both the requests.

Comment: post the full response you get(not just the body) from both systems; preferably in a gist or something.

Comment: @PNY . I have updated the question with full response.